# Cross table update in Firebird SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

Maybe somebody knows how to do that. In MySQL I would do as follows:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.c2 = T2.c2
WHERE T1.c1 = T2.c1
```

Unfortunately this results in an error when trying this in Firebird and yields the following response:

```
SQL Message : -204
Undefined name

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -204
Table unknown
T1
At line 2, column 1
```

Somebody an idea?

Comment: that wouldn't work in mysql either

Answer (score 2):

Firebird [`UPDATE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update) statements can only reference a single table. To do what you want you have two options.

Using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE T1
SET c2 = (SELECT T2.c2 FROM T2 WHERE T2.c1 = T1.c1)
```

or using [`MERGE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge):

```
MERGE INTO T1
USING T2
ON T1.c1 = T2.c1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET T1.c2 = T2.c2
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>You need to mention both tables before you access them.</s>

Try:

```
UPDATE T1, T2
SET T1.c2 = T2.c2
WHERE T1.c1 = T2.c1
```

Or alternatively

```
update t1
  inner join t2
    on t1.c1 = t2.c1
  set t1.c2 = t2.c2
```

**edit**

apparently firebird doesn't support joins in updates, so try:

```
update t1
  set t1.c2 = (select c2 from t2 where c1 = t1.c1);
```

Comment: That doesn't work in Firebird only a single table (or updatable view) can be referenced in the update statement itself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's inconvenient

Comment: Agreed, but it is the only update defined in the SQL standard; for more complex applications there is `MERGE` (see my answer).

Comment: yeah, saw it. i hadn't heard of firebird until 15 minutes ago ;)